# Ag-grid how to find the current page for a specified row (with sorting enabled)?

Tags: ag-grid

I have a multi-page ag-grid with sorting enabled.

When a new item is added to the ag-grid, it may add it on a different page (not the currently visible page) depending on the sort selections. Is there a way to retrieve the page number for a specific row-number from the AG-grid api?

(Note that the row indexes are typically not in order when the ag-grid is in a sorted state.)

Comment: What is your row model, and how do you add new item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var goToPage = Math.floor(rowIndex / this.grid.gridOptions.api.paginationGetPageSize());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to show the new item, you could try `ensureNodeVisible` or `ensureIndexVisible`. It will hopefully work despite the pagination.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-scrolling

Comment: No, those only scroll to the item if the item is on the current page, unfortunately.  The problem is when the item is added on a page that is not currently visible. I need a way to figure out which page they're added on so I can open the relevant page.